# Multidimensional generic array Java

Tags: java, generics, multidimensional-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java how to: Generic Array creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation)

I wanna create something like this:

```
public class MyClass<T> {
    private int row;
    private int column;
    private T[][] result;

    public T[][] generation(int size, T[] values) {
        result = new T[values.length][size];

        generator(0, 0);

        return result;
    }
}
```

But I'm gettin an error "generic array creation", how can I fix that? :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can get the type of `T` i.e. `Class<T>`, you can utilize [`Array.newInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,%20int...%29) as follows...

```
public T[][] generation(int size, T[] values) {
  result = (T[][]) Array.newInstance(values.getClass().getComponentType(),
      values.length, size);
  generator(0, 0);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: You could also use `values.getClass().getComponentType()` instead of having to pass in `type`.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to write a functional java BiFunction that converts a Generic list of lists into a generic bidimensional array as follows: `BiFunction<List<List<T>>, Class<T>,T[][]> toArray = (list,type) ->
 {
  T a[][] = (T[][]) Array.newInstance(type,
    list.size(), list.get(0).size());
  IntStream.range(0, a.length).forEach(i -> {
   a[i]=(T[]) list.get(i).toArray();
  });
  return a;
 };`

Answer (score 1):

new T is not possible, you have to use Object and cast before returning or after returning

Primitives are also not possible you have to use Integer, Float, etc.

Answer (score 0):

[java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance](http://bit.ly/NZxztC) is exactly what you need.

You only need an object of `Class<T>` but you could take one in the constructor of your class.

Comment: I saw the some topic but with one dimensional array. Can not understand how to get instance of multidimensional array.